# Backbone.js separate templates from html file

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am working on a Backbone.js application. We are using underscore.js templates to load the contents to the View. Currently we have all the templates inside the index.html file, so the size of the file is increasing. Can anyone help me to find a solution for separating these templates to other files? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Recently I have visited the [Backbone patterns](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns) and I found that we can use [JST templates](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#jst_templates) to create separate template files for each template. They explained that we can create a `jst.js` file to put all our template code:

```
// http://myapp.com/javascripts/jst.js
window.JST = {};

window.JST['person/contact'] = _.template(
    "<div class='contact'><%= name %> ..."
);

window.JST['person/edit'] = _.template(
   "<form method='post'><input type..."
);

<script src="http://myapp.com/javascripts/jst.js"></script>
```

Now all the templates are in the `jst.js` file. But if you have lots of templates and you want to move the templates to separate files you can create separate template files:

```
// http://myapp.com/javascripts/jst.js
window.JST = {};

//http://myapp.com/javascripts/contactPerson.template.js
window.JST['person/contact'] = _.template(
    "<div class='contact'><%= name %> ..."
);

//http://myapp.com/javascripts/editPerson.template.js
window.JST['person/edit'] = _.template(
   "<form method='post'><input type..."
);

<script src="http://myapp.com/javascripts/jst.js"></script>
<script src="http://myapp.com/javascripts/contactPerson.js"></script>
<script src="http://myapp.com/javascripts/editPerson.js"></script>
```

Please let me know if there is any simpler idea. Thanks!

Comment: Look into separating your templates into files, and then compiling them into a js file before deployment. See asset packagers like http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/#jst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have templates in seperate html files and can load them as text using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). There is a plugin called [text](https://github.com/requirejs/text) which will help you to do that.

Example:

```
define([
  'text!templates/sampleTemplate.html'
], function(tmpl){

    var Sampleview = Backbone.View.extend({
      id: 'sample-page',

      template: _.template(tmpl),

      render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
     }
  });
  return SampleView;
});
```

The html file "templates/sampleTemplate.html" will be taken from the root path specified in the require.js config

Answer (score 1):

Load them via `xhr`.  The lib requirejs (requirejs.org) loads html file dependencies this way. This will work when in development, but the templates should be compiled into the js files in production.