# Can you put a JST template inside a _.template function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to do this in backbone:

```
@modal_template = _.template(JST["templates/collaborators/share_auditions_modal"])
```

It should store the template JST file to the @modal_template variable. Although it doesn't work. I can't just put the template in a "template:" within the view because this is just within an event within that view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with JST approach, but I think you have the syntax backwards. Probably you want to take the compiled underscore template and place it into the JST object for later use:

```
window.JST['person/contact'] = _.template(
    "<div class='contact'><%= name %> ..."
);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033996/backbone-js-separate-templates-from-html-file) for more info and also [this article](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#jst_templates) which is the source of the above code snippet.